# Set default image style in CKEditor

Tags: css, ckeditor, ckfinder

I'm using CKEditor with CKFinder in a custom CMS.  Users upload and insert photos in articles and that works almost beautifully.   The downside is that the default image style is margin/padding:0px, so the images appear crowded when left or right aligned.

Is there a way to set up a default image style in CKEditor, so that when a user inserts an image (whether through CKFinder or entering direct HTML/Source), a padding:10px attribute is added as a style?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the styles within the editor here

[CKEditor 3.x Styles](http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/Styles)

Personally, I use the contentsCss configuration option to provide a stylesheet reference, like so:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function(config) {
    config.contentsCss = ['styles.css'];
};
```

And inside styles.css you could do:

```
img { margin: 10px; }
```

or whatever you want to do for images.